# R: Create a new column with driving distance between two coordinates using loop

Tags: r, api, loops, distance

I have a dataframe that looks something like the following. I am trying to create a new column that calculates the driving distance for each group between the *from* point and the *to* point. That column would look something like the last column, where "distance" would actually be replaced by driving distance.

```
# group point      lat         lon       distance
# 1     from    42.8138364  -70.8915412  NA
# 1     to      42.30167    -71.1288836  "distance"
# 2     from    42.3317772  -72.6541784  NA
# 2     to      42.8138364  -70.8915412  "distance"
# 3     from    42.3317772  -72.6541784  NA
# 3     to      42.0788833  -72.0414925  "distance"
```

The `ggmapsdistance` package seems to be able to computate distance, but I'm not too sure how to include in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have acquired the API key for that package.

Your data:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~group, ~point , ~lat, ~lon,  ~distance,
  1,     "from" ,   42.8138364,  -70.8915412,  NA,
  1,     "to"    ,  42.30167   , -71.1288836,  "distance",
  2,     'from'   , 42.3317772,  -72.6541784,  NA, 
  2,     'to'      ,42.8138364,  -70.8915412,  "distance",
  3,     'from'    ,42.3317772,  -72.6541784,  NA,
  3,     'to'      ,42.0788833,  -72.0414925,  "distance"
) 

# A tibble: 6 x 5
  group point   lat   lon distance
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
1     1 from   42.8 -70.9 NA      
2     1 to     42.3 -71.1 distance
3     2 from   42.3 -72.7 NA      
4     2 to     42.8 -70.9 distance
5     3 from   42.3 -72.7 NA      
6     3 to     42.1 -72.0 distance
```

Reformatting the data

```
df %>%
  unite(col = "geo", c(lat, lon),
        sep = "+") %>%
  select(-distance) %>%
  spread(point, geo)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  group from                   to                    
  <dbl> <chr>                  <chr>                 
1     1 42.8138364+-70.8915412 42.30167+-71.1288836  
2     2 42.3317772+-72.6541784 42.8138364+-70.8915412
3     3 42.3317772+-72.6541784 42.0788833+-72.0414925
```

Get distance between points

```
df %>%  
  mutate(distance = map2(from, to, 
                         function(from, to) 
                           gmapsdistance(from, to, mode = "driving", 
                                         key = "YOU_GOOGLE_KEY_HERE")$Distance) %>% unlist) 

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  group from                   to                     distance
  <dbl> <chr>                  <chr>                     <dbl>
1     1 42.8138364+-70.8915412 42.30167+-71.1288836      70718
2     2 42.3317772+-72.6541784 42.8138364+-70.8915412   207442
3     3 42.3317772+-72.6541784 42.0788833+-72.0414925    84934
```